# Old Desktop will not boot Freya 0.3.2 i386 CD

Tags: release-freya, boot

great problem with very old desktop.
System is an old AMD Athlon XP 1900+ on a ASUS A7V600-X MoBo with NVIDIA GeForce3 Ti200.
System support CD-Boot only! No USB-Stick or HD work as boot device.
Installing Luna-i386 will open the installation window and install everything OK.
After reboot i get the Luna background picture and a black window in the middle of the screen. Nothing more.
No panel no plank. Pressing strg-alt-t i got a terminal without window and can type blind, that work.
Struggling with terminal over grub-boot i found NVIDIA driver is loaded and graphic-card is well.

So i stopped fighting with Luna and try Freya i386 0.3.2
CD wont boot! The shift-key wont work to get options, "e" wont work, nothing happens.
After a while the normal boot occurs. No message, no error, nothing.
No problem, new .iso - new cd - next try - no luck!

Any help is welcome

Comment: I don't think an CD iso of Elementary OS exists, where did you grab it ?

Comment: I added an answer for the question. Mark it as answer if it works

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your system does not support booting from a USB try using PLoP boot manager. First you will need to copy elementary OS to a USB using Rufus.

## How to install PLop boot manager

#### Install PLoP on a CD

PLoP comes as a ZIP file, which includes different files. To install PLoP on a CD, you will need either **plpbt.iso** or **plpbtnoemul.iso** from that ZIP file. Both disc images should work on most computers, though if in doubt **plpbtnoemul.iso** should work “everywhere,” according to read me included in the ZIP

Burn **plpbtnoemul.iso** or **plpbt.iso** to a CD.

#### Booting elementary OS from PLoP

Plug in your USB and insert your CD .Boot you computer from the CD and PLoP boot manager will load. It will look something like the following

[image: PLoP]

Select your elementary OS USB and press <kbd>ENTER</kbd>

Comment: You made my day. Thanks. Installation runs fine. But the VGA will use nouveau driver and screen is black. I will try to load NVIDIA driver to fix.